# subprocess.Popen executes .sh differently then subprocess.call

Tags: python

I'm trying to run parsey mcparseface from a subprocess. I get different results when running Popen vs call and I'm wondering why this is.
This works.

```
process = subprocess.Popen("./syntaxnet/demo.sh", cwd="/home/kahless/models/syntaxnet")
```

This does not.

```
process = subprocess.call("./syntaxnet/demo.sh", cwd="/home/kahless/models/syntaxnet")
```

Both execute without python throwing any errors but when running .call parsey does not complete correctly. This also happens when using .wait() or .communicate() with Popen. What I'm trying to do is pause the execution of my code until parsey finishes. Not sure whats going on here.

Edit. When I say that parsey does not complete correctly I mean I am getting a different end result from running the demo.sh file. Here are the different outputs.

When things work correctly

INFO:tensorflow:Processed 10 documents
INFO:tensorflow:Total processed documents: 10
INFO:tensorflow:num correct tokens: 0
INFO:tensorflow:total tokens: 170
INFO:tensorflow:Seconds elapsed in evaluation: 0.18, eval metric: 0.00%
INFO:tensorflow:Processed 10 documents
INFO:tensorflow:Total processed documents: 10
INFO:tensorflow:num correct tokens: 10
INFO:tensorflow:total tokens: 153
INFO:tensorflow:Seconds elapsed in evaluation: 0.86, eval metric: 6.54%

When they do not.

INFO:tensorflow:Total processed documents: 0
INFO:tensorflow:Total processed documents: 0

Comment: Please define `parsey does not complete correctly`.

Comment: Sure I've updated my answer to show the output. Sorry about being vague.

Comment: Call blocks Popen does not.

Comment: Any idea why I would have the same issue when using communicate() according to the subprocess documentation it shouldn't block.

Comment: @Kahless - No, communicate() does wait for process completion like call() does.

Comment: Does your code do anything after `Popen` or `call` or does it just exit? Do you call your python program from the command line? Do you ctrl-c to end the program? I don't see how exiting early by itself makes a difference.`demo.sh` uses the parent `stdin` and unless it registers to receive `SIGHUP` it shouldn't matter whether the parent exits or not.

Comment: At this time It does not do anything after Popen But I would like it to. I'm running the program from Geany. Ctrl-c will exit out of the program. The demo.sh can be configured to get it's input from a file. I have done this. I'm also not sure why it matters. Maybe I'm just going about this the wrong way. I just want to run demo.sh as if I was running it like normal wait for it to complete and then run some more code. Can you think of a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it ever finishes?

Looks like your code hangs. Perhaps it takes user input?

`subprocess.call()` waits until it finishes so as `wait()` and `communicate()`

Comment: It shouldn't require any user input. But I think the demo.sh file might be calling other scripts. I'm not really sure. Here's a link to the code https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/syntaxnet/syntaxnet/demo.sh

Comment: Seems like the input is from stdin meaning user input

Comment: I see. Sorry I didn't realize what you meant. You can set it to get the input from a file instead. And that works when I run the demo.sh script directly.

Comment: So when running demo.sh from a subprocess it hangs when it's being told to wait because it's waiting for demo.sh to obtain the input from another file?

Comment: @Kahless You did not put the parameter that tells it to get input from a file.